# Class options don't work if class and document files are in different directories

Tags: expl3, latex3, paths, class-options, l3keys

I have the following directory tree:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── foo.tex
└── testcls
    └── testcls.cls
```

where `foo.tex` is

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../testcls/}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[hyperref=true]{testcls}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

and `testcls.cls` is

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\ProvidesExplClass{testcls}{}{}{}

\bool_new:N \l_hyperref_bool

\keys_define:nn { module }
  {
    hyperref .bool_set:N = \l_hyperref_bool,
    hyperref .initial:n = { false },
    hyperref .default:n = { true },
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { module }

\LoadClass{article}

\bool_if:NT \l_hyperref_bool { \RequirePackage{hyperref} }
```

in `testcls.cls` I'm using `l3keys2e` to have a key-value interface for class options. The only class option is a boolean `hyperref`, which controls the loading of the `hyperref` package.

Since I'm passing `hyperref=true` in `foo.tex`, I'd expect `hyperref` to be loaded, but it isn't.

However if I comment out

```
% \makeatletter
% \def\input@path{{../testcls/}}
% \makeatother
```

and specify `testcls.cls`'s path by calling it via

```
\documentclass[hyperref=true]{../testcls/testcls}
```

then `hyperref` gets loaded. What's going on here?

Comment: unrelated to the bug you found: I wouldn't use such a file layout. Loading a class by adjusting `\input@path`  in a file look quite wrong. Why don't you put the class in some texmf in a standard search path?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have a class for typesetting lecture notes, which I update/modify every semester. If I were to put it in my local texmf tree, then changing something for the second semester's class would mean my first semester's class wouldn't compile. By putting the class in a different folder for every semester I can make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Putting the class locally with the notes makes sense, but changing \input@path for that does  not. This is an internal "system" command that should be set based on the behavior of the TeX implementation but not to cater for loading one individual file because it is likely to affect file loading then in other cases. So the correct solution for loading a locally stored file is indeed to  call it as you did via \documentclass[hyperref=true]{../testcls/testcls}. That doesn't mean the issue introduced should not get fixed though, but please stop (mis)using \input@path

Comment: To be honest I suspected what I was doing was probably not the proper way, but using `../testcls/testcls` brings up two problems: 1) LaTeX complains about `You have requested document class '../testcls/testcls', but the document class provides 'testcls'`. I'd have to `\ProvidesExplClass{../testcls/testcls}{}{}{}`, but that looks weird, and similarly 2) a `\input{baz.tex}` in my class file would have to become `\input{../testcls/baz.tex}`, which looks even weirder since `testcls.cls` and `baz.tex` are in the same folder.

Comment: well as I wrote: I would use a standard search path. And I would try to write the cls so that it is more permanent, and put modifications in some file `changes-sem-2020-2.sty`  or so, that can be loaded through some option.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've just `sudo tlmgr update --all` but I'm still experiencing the bug. Has this not been resolved upstream?

Comment: @noibe Sorry, I forgot to update you.  It's been fixed in the repository ([this pull request](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/416), more specifically [this](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/a9b93b3) and [this](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/978bf8f) commit), but we've decided not to send it as an intermediate fix in `firstaid`, instead wait for the next patch release (I belive in a week or so).  I've just added a reminder to let you know when this fix gets to TeX Live. Meanwhile, the fix in my first comment is (a bit cleaner but) roughly what will go into the release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been fixed in the repository ([this pull request](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/416), more specifically [this](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/a9b93b3) and [this](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/978bf8f) commit). Yesterday (2020-10-27) patch level 2 was uploaded to CTAN, so the update is already available:

```
[ 6/11, 00:56/04:17] update: latex [23033k] (56606 -> 56775) ... done
```

(might take a while, depending on which mirror you use).